# Blender crash exception_access_violation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

2.77 crashes when attempting to render a cycles scene when using an image texture. Only adding an image to a cube in the standard scene then rendering from preview or full render blender crashes, doing the same in blender render works. Other versions have been tried but getting the same result.
Both CPU and GPU have been attempted used.
OS: Windows 10 x64
Graphics: GTX 750 ti 2gb
Ram: 16gb
CPU: AMD FX-8120
Render engine: Cycles

Comment: there is not enough info to help you. are you using the GPU or CPU? are you running out of memory?

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: 4128x2322
1,30 MB
Richtone(HDR)
jpg
Tested now with a non HDR image and blender didn't crash.

Comment: Also did a test with some older and darker HDR images which worked